# Adding info to git config aliases command

Tags: git, bash, terminal

I want to add the values for the addition, modification, and deletion of files in a commit to this alias I created.  Which values can I use to insert this into thier own colored brackets? i.e: (M:37)-(A:2)-(D:1)

```
git config --global alias.lg "log --graph --all --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(bold white)— %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --abbrev-commit --date=relative”
```

The photo is what the command looks like now.[image: Command Line]

Comment: How about `--shortstat`?